# Petition Purpose: Disclaimer in the certain Stack Overflow blog post

Tags: discussion, welcoming

This is a purpose of a petition to the Stack Overflow team or Jay Hanlon personally about the now [famous/infamous blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Disregarding the disagreement about the point of views and some description in the blog post, I am all for anyone expressing their point of view. Yet since the post is on official Stack Overflow blog post, I would hope that there can be some disclaimer to disassociate it with the common thought in the SO community:

> Disclaimer: This is a blog post by personal/Stack Overflow company, and does not any other Stack Overflow community members.
>       The author is not an active user of the Stack Overflow website.

[image: The disclaimer should be placed at the top of the article, after the byline and before the first paragraph.]

**WHY:**

I purpose this mainly because I feel falsely represented on both the *fact* the blog post trying to display, which has been [discussed thoroughly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming) in many meta posts already, and the many "we" inside the blog post. And I would like to see if the community share my concerns.

AFAIK the blog poster is [not an active participant of the Stack Overflow community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347414/jaydles?tab=topactivity), and doesn't seem to be willing to engage some of the questions raised for him on meta SO, I feel we need some clarification on the "we" that the author is pointing at, since I personally definitely don't share the view of the author, and I believe there are a good number of people in the community share my concerns to be included inside that "WE".

And again, this isn't about disagreement, but about the due respect that I believe the Stack Overflow community deserves. We deserve to not be involuntary represented. I hope we can stick this post on this specific topic rather than the right or wrong in the origin blog post.

Comment: I can clearly see in your screen grab where it says "by Jay Hanlon" right at the top of the article. This is pointless. It's time to stop beating this dead horse.

Comment: Like a dog to it's vomit, here we are again.

Comment: What do you mean by *"does not any other Stack Overflow community members"*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no real reason to need this.

That blog is the *company* blog. Only the company staff can post in that blog. Users cannot, random people on the internet cannot. Thus, most people would assume that those are the words of the *company* and not the *community.* A disclaimer is therefore not needed to tell people that those are the words of the company.

The "we"s that the author put in the blog post refer to *Stack Overflow the Company.*

The blog tries to reiterate several times that they mean only the company, and that they do not blame the community. They were trying to make it clear they did not blame us, only themselves.

Now if that post were made in a blog that any Stack Overflow contributor could post to, I would totally agree a disclaimer would be a good idea.

Comment: `It was hard to accept some of the (valid) criticism, especially the idea that women and people of color felt particularly unwelcome. There’s a weird paradox with bias. Those of us who have privilege, but care deeply about reducing bias should be uniquely positioned to help, but we struggle the hardest to recognize that we are (unintentionally) biased ourselves.` I agree mostly, but still there's lines that it wasn't really clear.

Comment: I certainly see spots where it may be a tad more ambiguous, hence my saying they were _trying._ (I totally agree there are spots where they weren't fully clear.) However, I find the biggest "disclaimer" that the blog is the views only of the company to be... Well, it's the company blog. That's my main reason for disagreeing with your proposal, really.

Comment: @tweray The "we" in this specific passage refers neither to the community nor to the company. It is a generic "we", meant to encompass everyone who identifies with the characterisation ("Those of us who [...]"), regardless of affiliation.

Answer (score 21):

At no time does the blog post attempt to speak for the sentiments of Stack Overflow the community. I see no evidence that uses of "we" are intended to include "the community". "We" is clearly "the company" and/or "the site", not "the community". It is consistently used in that way.

Just consider the phrase, "We failed to give our regular users decent tools to review content and easily find what they're looking for". That clearly makes a distinction between "regular users" and "we".

You seem to be reading something into it that is not there.